# Angular Object doesn't support property or method 'scrollTo' with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11, scrolltop, scrollto

In my Angular 6 application i have a method which executes an auto scroll into the page. In Chrome it works fine, but in Internet Explorer (11) i get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'scrollTo'

This the function in my component:

```
 autoScroll(step) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let element = document.getElementById(step.stepId);
        if (element) {
            let el= document.getElementsByClassName("elements") && document.getElementsByClassName("elements")[0];
            if (el) {
                el.scrollTo({
                    top: 50,
                    behavior: "smooth"
                });
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a little stackblitz please ?

Comment: Do you used the correct polyfills?

Comment: It should be 'window.scrollTo()'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

document.querySelector('').scrollTop = 50

Use scrollTop, hope this will help you to resolve the problem.

Comment: It works! Is there a possibility to add an animation too? I tried with this:

mySelector.animate({50}, 500);

but i get this error:
Argument of type '{ scrollTop: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Keyframe[] | PropertyIndexedKeyframes'.

Comment: I recently applied this, but as far I know it has limited options for IE, means, options can't be set. but the same will work in other browsers for sure.

If my answer helped you in some way, please rate it. thanks

Comment: It doesnt work because i have the errore i wrote to you

Comment: Because IE have limited things, options can't be set

Comment: Sorry i missed to write that the previous error is given by visual studio code, and not by IE

Comment: Update the question then, it will help others

Comment: No, the error code i wrote as first comment to your question  "Argument of type '{ scrollTop: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Keyframe[] | PropertyIndexedKeyframes'.". I got that error when i tried to use your code

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable support for IE 11 in polyfills.ts file.